# sql get days incidence in a specific month

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to make a query on mysql that return the incidence in days of a course on a specific month, i will explane better with an example:

```
Course A
start 2018-10-18 end 2018-11-16 (incidence in november 16 days
Course B
start 2018-11-05 end 2018-11-05 (incidence in november 1 days)
Course C
start 2018-10-05 end 2019-01-20 (incidence in november 30 days)
```

The month of incidence (ex. november) is dynamically selected by the user.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Do you only want november?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the november component of courses starting in november:

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(
  CASE WHEN start_date > '2018-11-01' THEN start_date ELSE '2018-11-01' END,
  CASE WHEN end_date <= '2018-11-30' THEN end_date ELSE '2018-11-30' END
) + 1
FROM 
  courses
WHERE NOT(start_date > '2018-11-30' OR end_date < '2018-11-01')
```

We basically run a test on the start and end date - if the start is before november, peg it to nov 1st. If the end date is after the end of november, peg it to the end of november. The query contains two dates - the front end app can provide these after the user picks november. A basic formula for finding the last date of a month is to go to the first date of the next month (i.e. same year, month +1, '01' as the day), minus one day

We want to exclude courses that end before or start after, hence the structure of the where clause..

Comment: the course B on my example start and end in november

Comment: @abalest14 if it worked for you. You should consider marking this as accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya sure, with a parameter or two from the user.. and I did give instructions on converting it thus. At the end of the day it is the logic that is generic, the dates therein are just specific examples to fit the stated question